# Particle origin when particle is a group

Tags: particles, groups

I want to create a tree, but I have a problem to distribute the twigs with leaves on my tree.

At first I created the tree.

Then I build some twigs and used a particle system to distribute the leaves on the twigs.

From what I've read here, it is not possible to place hair particles on an object, that contain another particle system. So I converted the leave particles on my twigs to real objects and parented them to the twig.
[image: Twigs]

So far, so good, but now I'm missing something. When I want to use these twig-groups as particles on my tree, they are floating around. The twigs don't start growing on my tree.
[image: Twig distribution]

I played around with some values, but nothing helps. 
When I use the particle system to just render the twig object instead of the whole group, everything is fine.

How do I get this whole group "origin" to align with the faces on my tree?

Comment: Please show all leaves and their origins in the groups that appears above.

Comment: Do you have a few leaves with different shapes?

Comment: It is not clear to me why you used a hair as the type.  Can you explain why you chose this?  What feature did you need?

Comment: My time may expire here soon.   Suggestion.  You know something more now.  Delete the particle system.  Enter a new particle System. Delete and Renew.   You may remove accumulated errors.  Show all setting of your particle systems.

Answer (score 2):

- Alternative 01. If you want a whole group to behave as one leaf.   duplicate the leaves ... then [Join] the new meshes into one single mesh.  You can change the origin of a single mesh in edit mode.

---

- Alternative 02. Deselect [Whole Group] if you want your leaves separate.

[image]

- When this is done increase the number of particles and bring image in 3D View up to date and inspect.  Increase or Decrease the number to suit your needs.

Comment: When I deselect whole group I will have twigs without leaves and some leaves on my tree.

Comment: That is a separate issue.  Do you mean that the leaf placement [location] is sometime correct and incorrect? Or do you mean you do not have enough leaves ... or something else?

Comment: When I deselect whole group, the placement is right. But the group consists of a twig (parent) and many leaves (children). This way, when I deselect whole group, I will have twigs on my tree (without leaves) and leaves that spawn on the "root stem".

Comment: You may choose to read again my post.  Make the changes listed above.